# php How to display values from an array into a li?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

i have a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
[5432980] => Array
    (
        [0] => 223
        [entry_id] => 223
        [1] => 138
        [elo_score] => 138
        [2] => 38
        [hits] => 38
    )

[2712949] => Array
    (
        [0] => 701
        [entry_id] => 701
        [1] => 128
        [elo_score] => 128
        [2] => 28
        [hits] => 28
    )
)
```

i get the array from here `$leader_array = fns_elo_search_entries();`

i  an trying to get each array (`[5432980], [2712949]`) in a li using `foreach`

something like this

```
<ul>
<li>load here the information from `[5432980]`</li>
<li>load here the information from `[2712949]`</li>
</ul>
```

i know that i need to use two foreach statements because is an multi-dimensional array
any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Why do you need two `foreach`? Once inside the first, you could access `5432980` keys directly.

Comment: The mix of integer keys and string keys is a bit funny, what is going on? Are the keys relevant or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate way, comma separated:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $values):

    echo "<li>{$key}: ".implode(', ', $values)."</li>";

endforeach;
```

`load here the information from [5432980]` is not too clear as far as what you want and how you want it formatted, so I simply gave an alternative to 2 foreach loops.

As mentioned in the comments, you can just access the keys directly.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $values):

    echo "<li>Score: ".$values['elo_score']."</li>";//etc.

endforeach;
```

Comment: i get the array from here `$leader_array = fns_elo_search_entries();`

Comment: and. how do i grab each individual value, if i want to display it?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($array as $valueArray)
{
   echo '<li>';
   foreach($valueArray as $value)
   {
     echo $value;
   }
   echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach($arrs as $arr){
  echo "<li>";
  foreach($arr as $a){
    echo "value: " . $a;
  }
 echo "</li>";
}

?>

</ul>
```

This is just basic formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<ul>";
array_walk($arr, 'ulli');
echo "</ul>";
function ulli(&$value, $index){
    if(is_array($value)){
        echo "<ul>";
        array_walk($value, 'ulli');
        echo "</ul>";
    }else{
        echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
    }
}
```